# Android select an image from the gallery and resize it before I pull it in

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-bitmap

I'm running into issues with the images in my gallery being much much larger than I need them to be.

I've looked for ways to reduce their size before I actually pull them in, but I'm just not quite putting it together as most of what I'm finding deals with BitMap resources and not a BitMap that already exists in the gallery.

So, basically, I am getting the image like so,

```
  imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

But before I actually assign it to my BitMap var over there I need to scale it down to a reasonable size for a phone.

Any help with understanding what is going on here better is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`getBitmap()` is a weak convenience method. Its body is a whopping four lines of code:

```
public static final Bitmap getBitmap(ContentResolver cr, Uri url)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(url);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is why I don't bother teaching people about it.

IMHO, the best solution is for you to use one of the [many image-loading libraries available for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Most of the good ones can load from a `Uri` and handle your resizing as part of the operation, doing the heavy lifting on a background thread.

If, for whatever reason, you want to do all that work yourself, call `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` with a `BitmapFactory.Options` object. In particular, set `inSampleSize` to indicate that you want the image to be resampled as part of reading it, so you wind up with a smaller `Bitmap` taking up less heap space.

Comment: Oh man....this is exactly the answer I was looking to get because it made me realize that what I was doing didn't even really need to work with Bitmaps at all, I can just directly use the Uri. 

That was the little piece that I was missing and it came about because I snatched someones code that used the getBitmap method without understanding what it was doing.

Thanks!